# C# Explicit Conversion Error

Tags: c#, list, observablecollection

Sharing the code below please  any one tell what is the error

```
  try
        {
            OrganoCollection = new ObservableCollection<HRM_Organogram>();

            foreach (var jobTypeDef in LobjWsHrmOeLinking.GetUnOccupiedRecordSearch())
            {


                OrganoCollection.Add(jobTypeDef);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ApplicationClass.Message(ex.Message, "Error", MessageType.Error);

         }
```

And the Definition of function is giving below this function is used throug a wcf service

```
    public List<HRM_Organogram> GetUnOccupiedRecordSearch()
    {
        List<HRM_Organogram> p_objMaster = new List<HRM_Organogram>();
        try
        {
            using (var context = new CMS_ERPEntities())
            {
                context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                var l_objMaster = (from OG in context.HRM_Organogram
                                   join OE in context.HRM_OELinking
                                       on OG.OrganoID equals OE.OrganoID
                                   where OE.FinalizeStatus == true
                                   select OG.OrganoID).ToList();

                p_objMaster = (from OG in context.HRM_Organogram
                               where !l_objMaster.Contains(OG.OrganoID)
                               && OG.Isactive==true
                               select OG).ToList();


        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return p_objMaster;
    }
```

And The Error is:

> Argument Type CMS_ERPClient.Service.HRM_OeLinking.HRM_Organogram is
>   Not Assianable to  CMS_ERPClient.Service.HRM_OrganGram.HRM_OrganGram

Comment: And i am getting error while i try to add jobtypedef variable to OrganoCollection.Add(jobtypedef).

Comment: The error is "Argument type CMSERPClient_Service.HRM_OElinking.HRM_Organogram is not assignable to parameter type CMS_ERPClientService.HRMORganogram.HRMOrganoGram"

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one type called `HRM_Organogram`, one in the namespace `CMSERPClient_Service.HRM_OElinking` and one in the namespace `CMS_ERPClientService.HRMORganogram`. You are trying to add the latter to a collection of the former. Check your `using` statements.

And if I may say, your namespace and type names are awful! Refactor them to have more descriptive and distinctive names and you'll have a much more enjoyable coding experience!

My guess is one is a DTO type and one is a Model type, and you'll have a mapper somewhere to do a conversion. I also guess this sentence won't mean a whole lot to you - try to see how these types are used elsewhere and look for code that has `using` statements for both and converts one to the other.

Comment: so i dont know how to convert